# What is the difference between type = "response" and type = "scores" in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand the predict function in R

There is a parameter called type which I can set to  "response" or "scores"

I'm having difficulty understanding the difference.

Thanks.

Comment: `predict()` is a generic function. It behaves differently depending on the class of the first object you pass to it. You can see all the different versions by running `methods(predict)`. Do you know which version you are using? Have you checked the help page for that version (i.e. `?predict.nls`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't precisely an answer, but it shows how I looked through all of the `predict()` methods available in base R to see what the possible values of `type` were for all of those methods ...

```
m <- methods("predict")
p <- lapply(m,getAnywhere)
tt <- function(x) {
  obj <-  formals(x$objs[[1]])
  r <- eval(obj$type)
}
res <- setNames(lapply(p,tt),
         sapply(p,"[[","name"))
res[!sapply(res,is.null)]
```

Results:

```
$predict.glm
[1] "link"     "response" "terms"   

$predict.lm
[1] "response" "terms"
```

So, you're going to have to tell us what S3 `predict()` method allows `type="scores"` as an option ...

Googling `cran predict type="scores"`: maybe the `pls` package?

From `?predict.mvr`:

> When ‘type’ is ‘"scores"’, predicted score values are returned for
>        the components given in ‘comps’.  If ‘comps’ is missing or ‘NULL’,
>        ‘ncomps’ is used instead.

I *believe* that the score values are the predicted principal component scores for a given set of predictors (as opposed to the predicted values of the original predictor variables).